# Rejecting the transaction doesn't catch the error in try-catch block

Tags: solidity, blockchain, metamask, javascript

I am working on a Dapp porject ,Where I have to catch the metamask error.
Here is my code:

```js
import React, {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useState,
} from "react";
import { useAccount, useWalletClient, usePublicClient } from "wagmi";
import { getContract, getWalletClient } from "@wagmi/core";
import { abiSUM, abiDIV } from "../contracts";
import { ethers, BrowserProvider } from "ethers";
import { useWaitForTransaction } from "wagmi";

const GlobalContext = createContext();

export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { address, isConnected, isDisconnected } = useAccount();

  const [sumState, setsumState] = useState({
    provider: null,
    signer: null,
    contract: null,
  });

  const [divState, setdivState] = useState({
    provider: null,
    signer: null,
    contract: null,
  });

  const [errorMessage, seterrorMessage] = useState("");
  const [tx, setTx] = useState("");
  const { isLoading, isSuccess, error } = useWaitForTransaction({
    hash: tx.hash,
  });

  const contractInstance = async () => {
    const contractAddressSUM = import.meta.env.VITE_CONTRACT_ADDRESS_SUM;
    const contractAddressDIV = import.meta.env.VITE_CONTRACT_ADDRESS_DIV;
    const contractABISUM = abiSUM;
    const contractABIDIV = abiDIV;
    try {
      const { ethereum } = window;

      if (ethereum) {
        const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(ethereum);
        const signer = await provider.getSigner();
        const contractSUM = new ethers.Contract(
          contractAddressSUM,
          contractABISUM,
          signer
        );
        setsumState({
          provider: provider,
          signer: signer,
          contract: contractSUM,
        });
        console.log("ContractSUM", contractSUM);

        const contractDIV = new ethers.Contract(
          contractAddressDIV,
          contractABIDIV,
          signer
        );
        setdivState({
          provider: provider,
          signer: signer,
          contract: contractDIV,
        });
        console.log("ContractDIV", contractDIV);
      } else {
        alert("Please install metamask");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isConnected) {
      contractInstance();
      console.log("Connected");
    }
  }, [isConnected]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (errorMessage) {
      const parsedErrorMessage = errorMessage?.reason
        ?.slice("execution reverted: ".length)
        .slice(0, -1);
      if (parsedErrorMessage) {
        console.log(parsedErrorMessage);
        alert(parsedErrorMessage);
        // setShowAlert({
        //   status: true,
        //   type: "failure",
        //   message: parsedErrorMessage,
        // });
      }
    }
  }, [errorMessage]);

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider
      value={{
        address,
        isConnected,
        isDisconnected,
        sumState,
        divState,
        tx,
        setTx,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};
export const useGlobalContext = () => useContext(GlobalContext);
```

The `catch (error) {console.log(error);}` doesn't print any error in the console. But the `inpage.js` and `error.ts` is returning the errors.
[image: Errors when rejecting tx]

**How can I catch the errors and print them ?**

Answer (score 0):

You should try ...catch in functions setsumState and setdivState.